# How to keep Firebase realtime database schema compatible in desktop application?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a desktop application and added support for the Firebase realtime database. Because I am running a desktop application users will run different versions of my app.

As my app evolves, new features will be added and **may** require an update to the database schema as well. But I can't do this as I need to keep all client versions compatible.

For example, I have projects saved in the database at `project/${uid}/${projectName}`. Imagine in the future projects are not anymore tied to a user because I implement "collaboration" and want to change this path. How would I do this to keep all my clients up running?

Comment: It's entirely up to you to determine if and how to evolve your database schema over time.  There is no guided path for this.  In fact, there is nothing unique about this for Realtime Database - any API for any type of client app that changes over time requires some form of versioning or change management.  It's a difficult problem to solve elegantly, and there are many ways to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store that path in realtime database and fetching the URL on client as required. I'm not sure what you mean by implement "collaboration" but if you want all the users to be on same version of your application then you would have to store the latest version in DB and verify the version yourself on client.

> projects are not anymore tied to a user

In my opinion, if you could store a list of user UIDs who are a part of that project then that would be easier instead of structuring your app as `projects/${uid}/projectname`. If it is something like `/projects/${projectId}` then storing that list of authorized users would be much more easier.

There's  [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config).

> Firebase Remote Config is a cloud service that lets you change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an app update.

You may have to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest) if your are building apps for desktop. Also as @Doug mentioned in comments, it may not synchronize all clients at same time.

Comment: Remote Config isn't going to get you 100% there.  It's just a feature flag toggle, and there is no guarantee that all client apps will all see the same config values at the same moment in time.  Synchronizing an update to be 100% consistent among apps is a very difficult problem to solve without imposing some sort of explicit version control or managed downtime.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. Using realtime db or any database would be a better way then.

Comment: The database itself doesn't matter at all.  All databases have data migration issues when changing schemas.  The problem is common among anything with APIs that change.  Something has to manage that change consistently from the point of view of the client app, or downtime must be forced to get everything in sync.

Comment: If that's the status, I would accept this as an answer as it gives me insights that I didn't miss anything obvious ;-)

Comment: @HelloWorld imo you should plan for what features you may be adding later on and write the db that way. You maybe able to remotely update the path where the app is supposed to write in database but you must make sure your backend / database accepts that data. i.e. proper security rules and doesn't overwrite any important data.